# Stone bridge vs. Stony bridge

Tags: word-usage

It might sound weird but one of my students asked me if there is a difference between 'a stone bridge' and 'a stony bridge'! Well off the top of my head I said it's the matter of collocation: we normally say stone bridge... like glass tower... stony is general while we use stone bridge with proper names like 'Stone Arch Bridge'

Does my answer make sense to you?

Comment: It's not really made clear in some (perhaps most) dictionaries, but the attributive noun _stone_ is standard for 'built of stone'. Check the numbers of Google hits for "stone bridge" and "stony bridge" (and notice how many of the latter hits involve quirky usages).

Comment: Go easy on him, he's only humany.

Answer (score 5):

The adjective "stony" means

> covered with or full of small pieces of rock.

But in the case of "stone bridge", we're saying "a bridge made out of stone" (As Edwin pointed out, stone in this case is an attributive noun) not "a bridge covered with small pieces of rock". So "stony bridge" wouldn't quite be accurate.

Comment: The problem is I've checked it in some dictionaries and tgis definition also came up: made of stones like stony steps. I got alittle confused http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stony

Comment: What definition?

Comment: I just put it up there. Made of stone as a sense of stony

Comment: That is true, but as it's a secondary definition I'd probably still lean towards using "stone".

Comment: Anyway, thank you guys for your help ☺ That was a relief 